# JQuery - get(0) undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I have this HTML structure:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <div id="accordion">
        <!-- 1st header and pane -->
        <img src="horisontalTabsAccordion/images/button1.jpg" />
        <div style="width:200px; display:block"><h3>Apolonija, zubarska ordinacija</h3><p>Nesto pise malo vise malo manje :)</p></div>

        <!-- 2nd header and pane -->
        <img src="horisontalTabsAccordion/images/button2.jpg" />
        <div><h3>Apolonija, zubarska ordinacija</h3><p>Nesto pise malo vise malo manje :)</p></div>

        <!-- 3rd header and pane -->
        <img src="horisontalTabsAccordion/images/button3.jpg" />
        <div><h3>Apolonija, zubarska ordinacija</h3><p>Nesto pise malo vise malo manje :)</p></div>

        <!-- 4th header and pane -->
        <img src="horisontalTabsAccordion/images/button4.jpg" />
        <div><h3>Apolonija, zubarska ordinacija</h3><p>Nesto pise malo vise malo manje :)</p></div>
    </div>
    <div id="buttons">
        <a href="#" class="btn-prev"><div class="previous-icon"></div></a>
        <a href="#" class="btn-next"><div class="next-icon"></div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to add buttons for activation next and previous tabs of current tab. Image element that is current have class "current".

The JS that i wrote have this form:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
var currentTab = $('#accordion').find('img.current');

$('.btn-prev').bind('click', function(){
    currentTab.prev('img').get(0).click();
    console.log("Previous");

    return false;
});

 $('.btn-next').bind('click', function(){
    currentTab.next('img').get(0).click();
    console.log("Next");

    return false;
});
```

});

I have error that says that is get(0) undefined. - TypeError: currentTab.prev("img").get(0) is undefined

Comment: I don't see any `img` element with a `current` class. Is this class being applied somewhere in your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.prev` gets the previous element **IF** it matches the selector, not the previous element **THAT** matches the selector.

Try this:

```
currentTab.prevUntil('img').prev().get(0)
```

`.next()` will need the same treatment with `.nextUntil`

You should also do some checking to prevent errors from pressing previous when you are on the first one.

Comment: you should be an english major, sir!

Comment: @user1461006 I don't see where you are changing the class of the image to current or not current

Comment: $("#accordion").tabs("#accordion div", {
    tabs: 'img',
    effect: 'horizontal'
  });

Comment: But this UI plugin have an extra movement that is not very nice. When you click onto tab(image in this case) the last tab got 10px movement. Accordion don't have fixed width because of that movement.

Comment: So... did my answer answer the question? Or are you still getting the same error.

Comment: Yes your answer is correct. Solved problem see pastie: pastie.org/4523579

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to call get(0) because prev get one or none.