# Previous and next div are always null

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have this HTML structure:

```
<body>
<div id="content" class="clearfix">
    <!-- Page 1 -->
    <div>
        <div class="description"><h2>Apolonija, zubarska ordinacija</h2><p>Nesto u vezi Apolonija zubarske ordinacije ce biti detaljno ispisano na ovom mjestu razlicito za svaki tab. Takodje moguce je dodati sliku kao sto je na slici dizajna.</p></div>
        <img src="content/images/ordinacija1.jpg" />
    </div>

    <!-- Page 2 -->
    <div>
        <div class="description"><h2>Apolonija, zubarska ordinacija</h2><p>Nesto u vezi Apolonija zubarske ordinacije ce biti detaljno ispisano na ovom mjestu razlicito za svaki tab. Takodje moguce je dodati sliku kao sto je na slici dizajna.</p></div>
        <img src="content/images/ordinacija2.jpg" />
    </div>

    <!-- Page 3 -->
    <div>
        <div class="description"><h2>Apolonija, zubarska ordinacija</h2><p>Nesto u vezi Apolonija zubarske ordinacije ce biti detaljno ispisano na ovom mjestu razlicito za svaki tab. Takodje moguce je dodati sliku kao sto je na slici dizajna.</p></div>
        <img src="content/images/ordinacija3.jpg" />
    </div>

    <!-- Page 4 -->
    <div>
        <div class="description"><h2>Apolonija, zubarska ordinacija</h2><p>Nesto u vezi Apolonija zubarske ordinacije ce biti detaljno ispisano na ovom mjestu razlicito za svaki tab. Takodje moguce je dodati sliku kao sto je na slici dizajna.</p></div>
        <img src="content/images/ordinacija4.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="navigation" class="clarfix">
    <div id="accordion">
        <!-- 1st header and pane -->
        <img src="horisontalTabsAccordion/images/button1.jpg" />
        <div style="width: 250px; display:block"><h3>Apolonija, zubarska ordinacija</h3><p>Nesto pise malo vise malo manje :)</p></div>

        <!-- 2nd header and pane -->
        <img src="horisontalTabsAccordion/images/button2.jpg" />
        <div><h3>Apolonija, zubarska ordinacija</h3><p>Nesto pise malo vise malo manje :)</p></div>

        <!-- 3rd header and pane -->
        <img src="horisontalTabsAccordion/images/button3.jpg" />
        <div><h3>Apolonija, zubarska ordinacija</h3><p>Nesto pise malo vise malo manje :)</p></div>

        <!-- 4th header and pane -->
        <img src="horisontalTabsAccordion/images/button4.jpg" />
        <div><h3>Apolonija, zubarska ordinacija</h3><p>Nesto pise malo vise malo manje :)</p></div>
    </div>
    <div id="buttons">
        <a href="#" class="btn-prev"><div class="previous-icon"></div></a>
        <a href="#" class="btn-next"><div class="next-icon"></div></a>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#accordion").tabs("#accordion div", {
      tabs: 'img',
      effect: 'horizontal'
    });
</script>
```

And I use this JavaScript's:
**buttons.js:**

```
var currentTab = null;
var choosenTab = null;

function bindTabs() {
// Set current tab variable when image is clicked
$('#accordion img').each(function() {
    $(this).bind('click', function() {
        currentTab = $(this);
    });
    });
}

function bindNext() {
$('.btn-next').bind('click', function(){ 
     choosenTab = currentTab.nextUntil('img').next();

     if (choosenTab.length != 0) { // Next image tag found
         choosenTab.get(0).click();
         currentTab = choosenTab;
     }
     return false;
});
}

function bindPrevious() {
$('.btn-prev').bind('click', function(){
    choosenTab = currentTab.prevUntil('img').prev();

    if (choosenTab.length != 0) { // Previous image tag found
        choosenTab.get(0).click();
        currentTab = choosenTab;
    }

    return false;
});
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
currentTab = $('#accordion').find('img.current');

bindTabs();
bindPrevious();
bindNext();
});
```

And **pager.js:**

```
var currentPageIndex = 0;
var currentPage = null;
var choosenPage = null;

function setCurrentPage() {
currentPage = $('#content > div:first-child');
}

function setInitialCurrentPage() {
$('#content > div:first-child').addClass("currentPage");
setCurrentPage();
choosenPage = currentPage;
}

function addRemoveCurrentPageClass() {
choosenPage.addClass('currentPage');
currentPage.removeClass('currentPage');
}

function preparePrevButton() {
$('.btn-prev').bind('click', function() {
    setCurrentPage();
    choosenPage = currentPage.prevUntil('div').prev();
    console.log(choosenPage); // Always is null

    if (choosenPage.length != 0) {
        addRemoveCurrentPageClass();
        currentPage = choosenPage;
    }
    return false;
});
}

function prepareNextButton() {
$('.btn-next').bind('click', function() {
    setCurrentPage();
    choosenPage = currentPage.nextUntil('div').next();
    console.log(choosenPage); // Always is null

    if (choosenPage.length != 0) {
        addRemoveCurrentPageClass();
        currentPage = choosenPage;
    }
    return false;
});
}

function prepareNavButtons() {
preparePrevButton();
prepareNextButton();
}

function prepareAcordionTabs() {

}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    setInitialCurrentPage();
prepareNavButtons();
prepareAcordionTabs();
});
```

The problem occurs when i want to find next or previous div of current div. Current div is one that have class "currentPage".

If someone want to have all source code can use Mercurial and pull data from Google code.
The google code project site is: https://code.google.com/p/apolonia-slide-pager/

Comment: your question is better suited to codereview

Comment: Why are you using `currentPage.nextUntil('div').next()` and not `currentPage.next()`? The `.next()` method returns the next _sibling_, which is what you want. You don't need `.nextUntil()`.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994701/jquery-get0-undefined

Comment: The html structure in that other question was different. The html structure shown in _this_ question has the "pages" as siblings, so `.next()` will work. Again, you don't need `.nextUntil()`.

Comment: Can you narrow down your code to only relevant sections where the error occurs and/or reproduce a small test case on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Thanks now it works. nextUntil('div').next() chenged to only next()